# Loop through each cell in range vertically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop that goes through two-dimensional range

```
set rng = Range("A1:C3")

For each cell in rng 
    Debug.Print cell.value
next cell
```

It prints like:

```
A1
B1
C1
A2
B2...
```

I would prefer:

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2...
```

I know there is a way to do that looping with indexes but for each is much more elegant and on the top of that my range can be non-contiguous like:

```
Range("A1:C3,G9:H16,B14:D18")
```

Is there a way how to change default (horizontal) excel behavior?

Comment: Don't loop through cells. Doing so is the opposite of best practice. Instead, bring all of the cell values you care about into a Variant array all in one shot and then loop through the array. Depending on the number of cells in total this suggestion can literally be THOUSANDS of times faster. For example: `v = Range("A1:C3").Value2' Once that line is executed,`v` will be a 2-dimension Varaint array and you can loop through that. You can loop through the columns or rows and it will work for a non-contiguous range as well.

Comment: `For Each` is not more elegant. When working with the Excel object model from VBA you should make every effort to minimize the communication between the VB runtime and the Excel application. The communication between the two is extremely slow... which is the last thing you want in a tight loop!

Comment: You are of course absolutely right. I am just not sure about that non-contiguous part. When I did `arr = Range("A1:C3,C9:D11").Value2` and then printed each item in that array, it returned only `A1:C3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range, rRow As Range, rCol As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:C3")
    For Each rCol In rng.Columns
        For Each rRow In rCol.Cells
            Debug.Print rRow.Value
        Next rRow
    Next rCol
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

### Loop Through the Cells of a Non-Contiguous Range (Multi-Range)

**By Areas**

- The numbers in the yellow cells in the image are illustrating the looping order by areas and by rows. The results of the procedures in the `J` and `K` columns are copied from the Immediate window and are showing both of the looping orders.

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteCellsByAreaRows()

    Const sAddress As String = "A1:C3,G9:H16,B14:D18"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim mrg As Range: Set mrg = ws.Range(sAddress)
    
    Dim arg As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    For Each arg In mrg.Areas
        For Each aCell In arg.Cells
            Debug.Print aCell.Address(0, 0) & " = " & aCell.Value
        Next aCell
    Next arg

End Sub

Sub WriteCellsByAreaColumns()

    Const sAddress As String = "A1:C3,G9:H16,B14:D18"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim mrg As Range: Set mrg = ws.Range(sAddress)
    
    Dim arg As Range
    Dim acrg As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    For Each arg In mrg.Areas
        For Each acrg In arg.Columns
            For Each aCell In acrg.Cells
                Debug.Print aCell.Address(0, 0) & " = " & aCell.Value
            Next aCell
        Next acrg
    Next arg

End Sub
```

### EDIT

**Area Independent (The Challenge)**

- The numbers in the yellow cells in the image are illustrating the looping order by rows. The results of the procedures in the `J` and `K` columns are copied from the Immediate window and are showing both of the looping orders.

[image]

**Short Function Description (By Columns)**

- It will loop through the columns of each area and write the column number to an Array List which will finally be sorted. When looping through the elements of the Array List (each column number), a reference to the intersection of the worksheet column and the initial multi-range will be created and each single range reference will be written to an array. The array will be (bubble) sorted by the row numbers of every single column range and then will be added as an element of the resulting array of arrays.

```vb
Sub WriteCellsByColumn()

    Const sAddress As String = "A1:C3,G9:H16,B14:D18"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim mrg As Range: Set mrg = ws.Range(sAddress)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If mrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ColumnRanges As Variant: ColumnRanges = GetSortedColumnRanges(mrg)
    If IsEmpty(ColumnRanges) Then Exit Sub ' e.g. 'ArrayList' is not working
    
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    For a = 0 To UBound(ColumnRanges)
        For b = 0 To UBound(ColumnRanges(a))
            For Each cCell In ColumnRanges(a)(b).Cells
                Debug.Print cCell.Address(0, 0) & " = " & cCell.Value
            Next cCell
        Next b
    Next a
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the sorted column range references of a range ('mrg')
'               in an array of arrays.
' Remarks:      Supports non-contiguous ranges (multi-ranges).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetSortedColumnRanges( _
    ByVal mrg As Range) _
As Variant
    If mrg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    On Error Resume Next ' The ArrayList needs 'Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5'.
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If arl Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim arg As Range ' Area (Single) Range
    Dim crg As Range ' Column Range (in Area Range)
    Dim cColumn As Long ' Column Number (of Column Range)
    For Each arg In mrg.Areas
        For Each crg In arg.Columns
            cColumn = crg.Column
            If Not arl.Contains(cColumn) Then
                arl.Add cColumn
            End If
        Next crg
    Next arg
    arl.Sort
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = mrg.Worksheet
    
    ' Define the Multi Range Array ('mrgArr').
    Dim mrgArr As Variant: ReDim mrgArr(0 To arl.Count - 1)
    
    Dim icrg As Range ' Intersect Column Range (in Worksheet Column)
    Dim trg As Range ' Temp Range
    Dim trgArr() As Range ' Temp Range Array
    Dim Key As Variant '
    Dim aUpper As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each Key In arl
        Set icrg = Intersect(mrg, ws.Columns(Key))
        aUpper = icrg.Areas.Count - 1
        If aUpper = 0 Then
            ' Write current Intersect Row Range reference to Temp Range Array.
            ReDim trgArr(0 To 0): Set trgArr(0) = icrg
        Else
            ' Write current Intersect Row Range references to Temp Range Array.
            ReDim trgArr(0 To aUpper)
            For a = 0 To aUpper
                Set trgArr(a) = icrg.Areas(a + 1)
            Next a
            ' (Bubble) Sort the references by rows.
            For a = 0 To aUpper - 1
                For b = a To aUpper
                    If trgArr(a).Row > trgArr(b).Row Then
                        Set trg = trgArr(a)
                        Set trgArr(a) = trgArr(b)
                        Set trgArr(b) = trg
                    End If
                Next b
            Next a
        End If
        ' Write the current Temp Range Array to the current element
        ' of the Multi Range Array.
        mrgArr(n) = trgArr
        n = n + 1
    Next Key
    
    GetSortedColumnRanges = mrgArr

End Function


Sub WriteCellsByRow()

    Const sAddress As String = "A1:C3,G9:H16,B14:D18"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim mrg As Range: Set mrg = ws.Range(sAddress)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If mrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim RowRanges As Variant: RowRanges = GetSortedRowRanges(mrg)
    If IsEmpty(RowRanges) Then Exit Sub ' e.g. 'ArrayList' is not working
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    For a = 0 To UBound(RowRanges)
        For b = 0 To UBound(RowRanges(a))
            For Each rCell In RowRanges(a)(b).Cells
                Debug.Print rCell.Address(0, 0) & " = " & rCell.Value
            Next rCell
        Next b
    Next a
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the sorted row range references of a range ('mrg')
'               in an array of arrays.
' Remarks:      Supports non-contiguous ranges (multi-ranges).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetSortedRowRanges( _
    ByVal mrg As Range) _
As Variant
    If mrg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    On Error Resume Next ' The ArrayList needs 'Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5'.
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If arl Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim arg As Range ' Area (Single) Range
    Dim rrg As Range ' Row Range (in Area Range)
    Dim cRow As Long ' Row Number (of Row Range)
    For Each arg In mrg.Areas
        For Each rrg In arg.Rows
            cRow = rrg.Row
            If Not arl.Contains(cRow) Then
                arl.Add cRow
            End If
        Next rrg
    Next arg
    arl.Sort
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = mrg.Worksheet
    
    ' Define the Multi Range Array ('mrgArr').
    Dim mrgArr As Variant: ReDim mrgArr(0 To arl.Count - 1)
    
    Dim irrg As Range ' Intersect Row Range (in Worksheet Row)
    Dim trg As Range ' Temp Range
    Dim trgArr() As Range ' Temp Range Array
    Dim Key As Variant '
    Dim aUpper As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each Key In arl
        Set irrg = Intersect(mrg, ws.Rows(Key))
        aUpper = irrg.Areas.Count - 1
        If aUpper = 0 Then
            ' Write current Intersect Row Range reference to Temp Range Array.
            ReDim trgArr(0 To 0): Set trgArr(0) = irrg
        Else
            ' Write current Intersect Row Range references to Temp Range Array.
            ReDim trgArr(0 To aUpper)
            For a = 0 To aUpper
                Set trgArr(a) = irrg.Areas(a + 1)
            Next a
            ' (Bubble) Sort the references by rows.
            For a = 0 To aUpper - 1
                For b = a To aUpper
                    If trgArr(a).Column > trgArr(b).Column Then
                        Set trg = trgArr(a)
                        Set trgArr(a) = trgArr(b)
                        Set trgArr(b) = trg
                    End If
                Next b
            Next a
        End If
        ' Write the current Temp Range Array to the current element
        ' of the Multi Range Array.
        mrgArr(n) = trgArr
        n = n + 1
    Next Key
    
    GetSortedRowRanges = mrgArr

End Function
```

Comment: By column shouldn't 26 follow 8 ?

Comment: The loop is performed for one area at a time. What you're 'proposing' could be handled by using `Intersect` with additional complications. If you're in the mood, I would surely like to see it.

Comment: The idea I had was to loop the areas and determined the max row and column. Dimension an array(maxrow,maxcol) and fill it with the cell address of each cell in the areas array(cell.row,cell.column)  = cell.address. Then loop the array and skip the blanks.

Comment: @CDP1802: Since the `For...Each loop` doesn't work for rows either, I tried using a dictionary to get the rows and then loop through the keys and use `Set rrg = Intersect(srg, Rows(Key))`, but the problem is that e.g. the 10th row is `G14:H14,B14:D14` which will result in e.g. `23,24,20,21,22`. It looks like solving this ('sorting' the areas) is quite a challenge. Have no ideas so far.

Answer (score 1):

As a proof-of-concept with non-contiguous ranges that may overlap. Determine the lowest row and right most column of the areas, create a array that encloses all those areas, and fill it with the cell addresses of the cells in each area. Then traverse the array horizontally or vertically skipping over the blank entries.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo_by_column()

    Dim ar, a, cell As Range, rng As Range, i As Long
    Dim rmax As Long, cmax As Long, rmin As Long, cmin As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    rmin = Rows.Count
    cmin = Columns.Count
  
    ' non-contiguous range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:C3,D9:H16,B14:D18,A21:J21")

    ' dimension an array that encloses all the areas
    For Each a In rng.Areas
    
        r = a.Row + a.Rows.Count - 1
        If r > rmax Then rmax = r
        If a.Row < rmin Then rmin = a.Row
        
        c = a.Column + a.Columns.Count - 1
        If c > cmax Then cmax = c
        If a.Column < cmin Then cmin = a.Column
    
    Next
    ReDim ar(1 To rmax, 1 To cmax)

    ' fill array with cell addresses
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        For Each cell In a
            ar(cell.Row, cell.Column) = cell.Address
        Next
    Next
    
    ' loop the array by column, result to sheet2
    i = 1
    For c = cmin To cmax
        For r = rmin To rmax
            If Len(ar(r, c)) > 0 Then
                Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Range(ar(r, c))
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

   ' show array on sheet3
    Sheet3.Range("A1").Resize(rmax, cmax) = ar

End Sub
```

Comment: Great idea. The results are kind of hard to understand (to me). They became pretty clear after I did `rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow`, then manually put the (desired) incrementing numbers into the range (by columns) and used `ar(cell.Row, cell.Column) = cell.Address & " = " & cell.Value` and `Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = ar(r, c)`.